# Powershell: как выполнить пакет команд (*.ps1)?

Tags: powershell

Есть `ps1` файл с текстом:

```
$url = "https:\tttttttttttttttttttt"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$wc.Headers.Add('Authorization','Bearer gfgfgfgffgfgfgfgfg')
$res = $wc.downloadString( $url );
echo $res
```

Я хочу его выполнить из `powershell`:

1. если простонаписать имя файла (файл.ps1) находять в той же папке что и файл, и нажать ентер:

> `"Suggestion [3,General]: The command get_DocumentLikst_Json.ps1 was
>    not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell
>    does not load commands from the current location by default. If you
>    trust this command, instead type: ".\get_DocumentLikst_Json.ps1". See
>    "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details."`

2. если через `start "файл.ps1"` -  то открывается в нотпаде

Как его выполнить?
(пример - через `cmd bat-файл`, я так задумывал это)

Comment: *If you trust this command, instead type: ".\get_DocumentLikst_Json.ps1"*

Comment: спасибо, ".\get_DocumentLikst_Json.ps1" работает

Answer (score 1):

Если вы доверяете этому скрипту/комманде, вам следует писать путь до него через `.\`

> .\get_DocumentLikst_Json.ps1

спасибо за коментарий  [PetSerAl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181245/petseral)